# What is role of count in this program? Javascript Beginners

Tags: javascript

I came across this program and could not understand what role `count` plays here. Should it not be `var exponent=0;` and then increment it.

```
var power = function(base, exponent) {
var result = 1;
for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
result* = base;
return result;
};
console.log(power(2, 10));
```

Comment: First, it's not a *"program"*, it's a ***"javascript function"***... Then, `count` is an expression or variable declaration without special meaning (used here for the `loop`) Please read how it works the `for function` and it will be more clear to you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 2):

`exponent` is already a function `argument` (set to 10).
If you set inside your function (as you asked) back to `0`, than what?
Therefore you need a separate `counter` that starts from `0`.
Once the `counter` reaches `exponent` you get your result.

Also `result* = base;` should be `result *= base;`

Answer (score 0):

`count` keeps track of number of times that the base is multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

count is just a variable to keep track in the loop. See how you declare it with var?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else said, it's simply a counter variable that keeps track of the number of times you've multiplied the base.

An alternative that might make more sense is

```
var power = function (base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  while (exponent-- > 0) {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(power(2, 10));
```

As a note, if you're going to continue working in js I'd suggest checking out syntax standards in js. They make it infinitely easier for you and everyone else to read your code